# Generate Random Json data using Python and store in a varaible

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, for-loop, random

My app takes JSON in this format. How to use *for* loop to generate data in the mentioned format below, and store it in a variable?

Example with `id='123456'`:

```
{
    "abo": [

        {
            "id": "1ab",
            "data": fake.text(),
            "place": fake.place(),
            "user_id": id,
        },

        {
            "id": "1ab",
            "data": fake.text(),
            "place": fake.place(),
            "user_id": id,
        }
    ],
    "id": id
}
```

How to generate random data from this format and store them in a variable by given range?

If range is given as 3  (`for i in range(3)`)  it should dump the following.

```
{
    "abo": [

        {
            "id": "1ab",
            "data": this has been a great day,
            "place": texas,
            "user_id": '123456',
        },
        {
            "id": "1ab",
            "data": Gaurd should be credited,
            "place": newyork,
            "user_id": '123456',
        },
        {
            "id": "1ab",
            "data": fake.text(),
            "place": fake.place(),
            "user_id": '123456',
        }
    ],
    "id": '123456'
}
```

Tried this, but this isn't correct way to use json:

```
import json 
from faker import Faker
import random
from random import randint
print('{"abo": [')
fake = Faker('en_US')
for _ in range(20):
       data=
       {
            "id": "1ab",
            "data": fake.text(),
            "place": fake.place(),
            "user_id": id,
        }
    print(",")
    print(json.dumps(abo))

print('],"id": id}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close. Declare the list and append data to it.

**Ex:**

```
from faker import Faker

fake = Faker('en_US')

n = 3
id='123456'
data = { "abo": [], "id": id}        #!Update
for _ in range(n):
    data["abo"].append(              #!Update
        {
            "id": "1ab",
            "data": fake.text(),
            "place": fake.state(),   #!Update
            "user_id": id
            }
        )
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
{'abo': [{'data': 'Discuss glass trial game physical pressure. Task former '
                  'perhaps suggest your. Some that suddenly family '
                  'organization north assume.',
          'id': '1ab',
          'place': 'Texas',
          'user_id': '123456'},
         {'data': 'Brother energy expect check maybe itself attack. Power size '
                  'we tell.',
          'id': '1ab',
          'place': 'Alaska',
          'user_id': '123456'},
         {'data': 'Result become politics each line price describe. Magazine '
                  'vote society life dark physical although. Position read '
                  'president card away. Since strong opportunity morning '
                  'would.',
          'id': '1ab',
          'place': 'Ohio',
          'user_id': '123456'}],
'id': '123456'}
```

Comment: this i missing at the end -   ],"id": '123456'}

Comment: This is missing `print('],"id": id}')` at the end

Comment: Oh ok. Use `data = { "abo": [], "id": id}`